# HTML5 - setDragImage only works sometimes?

Tags: html, canvas, drag-and-drop

I have divs which are set draggable="true" and which have a dragstart handler. In the handle I setDragImage(image, 0, 0); and it usually works. But every fifth time or so I try to drag (and always the first time), it seems like the image isn't loaded and so the browser doesn't setDragImage.

How can I fix this and ensure the image is loaded/used as the drag image everytime? A friend of mine said canvas might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably image is not loaded in the point you call setDrawImage()

You might want to use an image preloader:

[Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)